# CSSinherit padding, then lessen the number

Tags: css

I have a class which is added to various sections of a site to show a section is editable. The class is named `.editable`

When a user is logged in, when they hover over such a section a red dashed border is shown around that section.

I do this currently like so:

```
.editable { /* add padding to act as clear border */
    padding:1px; 
}
.editable:hover { /* remove padding and add border */
    padding:0px; 
    border:1px dashed red 
}
```

As shown in the comments, I add a 1px padding so when border shows on hover, the section doesn't 'move'.

The problem arises when a section to be edited already has a padding. e.g.

```
.sectionToBeEdited {
    padding:10px;
}
```

When I add the .editable class `<div class="sectionToBeEdited editable">blah</div>` the padding is overwritten.

**QUESTION** Is there a way to inherit the padding setting and then add 1px to it? Then on hover reduce whatever padding by 1px.

I know another way to do this is to wrap the editable sections in separate divs and apply padding there but that involves rewriting and adding a lot of classes and divs.

Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

CSS can only override its values, there is no support for mathematical operations.

You can probably solve your problem by using a white/transparent border for your `editable` class instead of a padding.

```
.editable { /* change border color to something invisible */
    border:1px solid white;
}
.editable:hover { /* make border visible */
    border:1px dashed red;
}
```

Comment: You can have mathematical operations with calc(). But that doesn't help here.

Comment: This clearly only works on white backgrounds (or any other solid color if you change it), which doesn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: it might: http://www.researchkitchen.de/blog/archives/css-bordercolor-transparent.php

Answer (score 1):

Depend on browser support there are some choices available:

1. have `transparent` border and just change color to `red` on hover
2. use outline for the border `outline: 1px dashed red;` it won't affect box size
3. add `margin: -1px; border: 1px dashed red;` on hover so the box will be stretched by 1px on all sides

Answer (score 0):

This is what I went with:

```
.editable { 
    border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
.editable:hover { 
    border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Set the opacity of the border to 0 and 1 on hover

Comment: Have you tried `border: 1px solid transparent;` for the default state?

Comment: @AndreyKuzmin Yeah that works too I know, this gives a little more control if I choose to maybe show it at 0.8 on hover for example - but yeah, the first line could just be transparent